# Map (smooth) vertex group to a vertex color in geometry nodes

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, vertex-groups, shader-nodes, vertex-colors

I have a vertex group, which was painted using weight paint, called `trees`.
[image: vertex group]

I would like to use it in the shader editor to (smoothly) mix between two shaders. As I understand it, it's not possible to directly take the value of the vertex group weight there, so I would like to map the weights to a vertex color in geometry nodes:

[image: geometry nodes setup]

I made sure that the Viewer shows the correct colors (R=G=B, smoothly changing from 0 to 1).

I set the output value to a vertex color:
[image: geometry nodes output]

I then take the vertex color and use it in a diffuse shader, but I see the output being uniformly black:
[image: diffuse shader]

1. what went wrong here?
2. do you have a better workflow for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace the *Vertex Color* node by an *Attribute* node like this:

[image: Attribute node]

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect that you didn't set your GN's output type to "face-corner", which is what kind of data a vertex color layer is.

[image]

Notice the geometry nodes sidebar.  I've specifically designated the "Color" output as having an attribute domain of face corner.  Blender is showing you "face corner" in the properties/modifier tab not because the output is face-corner, but because the type of data to which you're outputting-- a vertex color layer-- is face-corner.  Apparently, there is no implicit conversion, which is a shame.

Note that there's a slightly simpler way to do what you want here, which is to just use an attribute node in your shader:

[image]

Here, I'm just passing my vertex group through a pass-through, which I'm using to convert from a vertex group to an arbitrary attribute.  I've made up a name for my output attribute and typed it in, then referenced that attribute in an attribute node in my shader nodes.  This works even as point data, as shown-- it *is* point data, as vertex groups are not face corner data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the GN outputs I chose "Face Corner > trees_c" (the highlight in the previous version of the screenshot was not what was selected, just hovered over when making the screenshot).

I tried what you proposed (pass trees directly, after returning it in GN), but weirdly, it doesn't work for me (again, everything is blacked out). Weirdly enough though, when I read trees_c attribute (the color one) as a factor, it does work as expected!

Comment: oki doki, I know what went wrong. For posterity, one needs to output in GN to a different attribute than the one it was reading from (when I renamed it to trees2 in GN outputs, it works fine). Thanks!

Comment: "in the GN outputs I chose "Face Corner > trees_c"" Like I said, face-corner in that dropdown does not mean the GN output type, it means the input type of trees_c the vertex color layer.  They need to be matched.